# IndexOutofBoundException at getChildView() Method in expandableListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am adding three child objects with name of All Homes All plots and All Commercial and i do it on run time i add these three objects with three parents that are Homes Plots and Commercial so in other terms i am adding three more categories in my Parents as child.i have done with it as whenever i load my expandableListview it loads the child on 0 index of my arrays but whenever i try to click on these newly created objects i get indexoutofboundexception error at method getChildView() as IndexOutOfBoundException invalid index 7 size is 7 and debugger show this error when i click on the child data is populated and when i navaigate back it shows this indexoutofBoundException Error at this method. The method Line where i am getting error is

```
rbSelect.setText(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition).getTitle());
```

my Code is.

```
package com.zameen.fragments;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.zameen.bl.AppController;
import com.zameen.bl.JsonParser;
import com.zameen.bo.PropertyTypeInfo;
import com.zameen.bo.PropertyTypeInfo.PropertyParent;
import com.zameen.dao.GetPropertyTypes;
import com.zameen.interfaces.PropertyTypeDidLoad;
import com.zameen.utils.GTMCall;
import com.zameen.utils.MyDialog;
import com.zameen.utils.Utils;
import com.zameen.utils.UtilsMethos;
import com.zameen.zameenapp.R;

public class Types extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
    private Context mContext;
    private View mView;
    public ArrayList<PropertyParent> childs;
    public PropertyParent parent;
    PropertyParent parent1;
    String value=" All";
    int selectedIndexChild = 0;
    int selectedIndexParent = 0;
    private Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = getActivity();

        Intent inetent = new Intent();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expendable_listview, container, false);
        mView.setOnClickListener(this);
        initItems();
        return mView;
    }
    private void initItems() {
        if(Utils.propertyTypesList != null){
            displayListListView();
        }else{
            //load data from server
            getPropertyTypes();
        }
    }

    private void displayListListView(){
        final ExpandableListView listview = (ExpandableListView)mView. findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        final ExpendableAdapter expendableAdapter = new ExpendableAdapter();
        //ArrayList<PropertyParent> childs = new ArrayList<PropertyParent>();
        //PropertyParent parent =   new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();
        PropertyTypeInfo property = new PropertyTypeInfo();

        for(int i=0;i<Utils.propertyTypesList.size();i++)
        {
        //  if( Utils.propertyTypesList.size()>0)
            //{

            property = Utils.propertyTypesList.get(i);
            //if(property.getParentId()=="1" && property!=null){
            if(parent==null)
            {


                 parent =   new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

                parent.setTypeId("9,8,21,22,20,24,25");
                parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
                parent.setTitleAlt2("All Houses");
                parent.setParentId("1");
                parent.setTitleAlt1("All House");
                childs= property.getChilds();
                childs.add(0,parent);


                }
            //}

                else if(parent.getTypeId().equals("9,8,21,22,20,24,25"))
                        {
                    parent =    new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

                    parent.setTypeId("12,23,11,19,26,27");
                    parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
                    parent.setTitleAlt2("All Plots");
                    parent.setParentId("2");
                    parent.setTitleAlt1("Residential Plot");
                    childs= property.getChilds();
                    childs.add(0, parent);


                }

                else if(parent.getTypeId().equals("12,23,11,19,26,27"))
                {
                    parent =    new PropertyTypeInfo().new PropertyParent();

                    parent.setTypeId("13,15,17,14,16,18");
                    parent.setTitle(value.concat(property.getTitle()));
                    parent.setTitleAlt2("All Commercial");
                    parent.setParentId("3");
                    parent.setTitleAlt1("Commercial");
                    childs= property.getChilds();
                    childs.add(0,parent);



                }

            //else
            //{




            //}





        }


    //  }

        expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listview.setAdapter(expendableAdapter);
        //expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                selectedIndexParent = groupPosition;
                selectedIndexChild = childPosition;
                expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Utils.userSearchInfo.setPropertyTypeName(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition).getTitle());
                Utils.userSearchInfo.setPropertyTypeParentIndex(selectedIndexParent);
                Utils.userSearchInfo.setPropertyTypeChildIndex(selectedIndexChild);
                Utils.userSearchInfo.setPropertyTypeId(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition).getTypeId());
                return true;
            }
        });

        if(Utils.userSearchInfo.getPropertyTypeId() != null){
            selectedIndexParent = Utils.userSearchInfo.getPropertyTypeParentIndex();
            selectedIndexChild = Utils.userSearchInfo.getPropertyTypeChildIndex();

        }else{
            selectedIndexParent = -1;
            selectedIndexChild = -1;

        }
        expendableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    private class ExpendableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ExpendableAdapter() {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Utils.propertyTypesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_item, parent, false);
            }
            TextView txtHeading = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeading);
            txtHeading.setText(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getTitle());
            ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
            eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);

            return convertView;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_item, parent, false);
            }
            RadioButton rbSelect = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

            rbSelect.setText(Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().get(childPosition).getTitle());
            if(selectedIndexChild == childPosition && selectedIndexParent == groupPosition){
                rbSelect.setChecked(true);
            }
            else{
                rbSelect.setChecked(false);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    private PropertyTypeDidLoad propertyTypeDidLoad = new PropertyTypeDidLoad() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<PropertyTypeInfo> typeList) {
            displayListListView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            MyDialog.showAlertDialog(mContext, message).show();

        }
    };
    //get property types from server
    private void getPropertyTypes(){
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(Utils.ServerActions.BASE_URL + UtilsMethos.getPropertyTypeURL(mContext));
        if(entry != null){
            try {
                final String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                if(data != null && data.length() > 0){
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String parseData = "";
                            try {
                                parseData = JsonParser.getValidJson(data, getString(R.string.property_type_key));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (VolleyError e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            PropertyTypeInfo[] locations = gson.fromJson(parseData,PropertyTypeInfo[].class);
                            Utils.propertyTypesList = UtilsMethos.convertArrayToList(locations);
                            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    propertyTypeDidLoad.onSuccess(Utils.propertyTypesList);

                                }
                            });


                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }else{

                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {     
                e.printStackTrace();

            } 
        }else{
            GetPropertyTypes propertyTypes = new GetPropertyTypes(mContext, propertyTypeDidLoad,true);
            propertyTypes.getTypes();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        GTMCall.pushOpenScreenEvent(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.gtm_screen_search_property_type));
    }
}
```

The Json View of my Data is

```
    "meta": {
        "status": "200",
        "mesaage": "Data Successfully Retrieved"
      },
      "response": {
        "type": [
          {
            "type_id": "1",
            "title": "Homes",
            "title_alt2": "Homes",
            "parent_id": "",
            "title_alt1": "Home",
            "child_list": "9,8,21,22,20,24,25",
            "childs": [
              {
                "type_id": "9,8,21,22,20,24,25",
                "title": "All Homes",
                "title_alt2": "All  Houses",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "All House"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "9",
                "title": "Houses",
                "title_alt2": "Houses",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "House"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "8",
                "title": "Flats",
                "title_alt2": "Flats & Apartments",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Flat"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "21",
                "title": "Upper Portions",
                "title_alt2": "Upper Portions",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Upper Portion"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "22",
                "title": "Lower Portions",
                "title_alt2": "Lower Portions",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Lower Portion"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "20",
                "title": "Farm Houses",
                "title_alt2": "Farm Houses",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Farm House"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "24",
                "title": "Rooms",
                "title_alt2": "Rooms",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Room"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "25",
                "title": "Penthouse",
                "title_alt2": "Penthouse",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "title_alt1": "Penthouse"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type_id": "2",
            "title": "Plots",
            "title_alt2": "Plots",
            "parent_id": "",
            "title_alt1": "Plot",
            "child_list": "12,23,11,19,26,27",
            "childs": [
              {
                "type_id": "12,23,11,19,26,27",
                "title": "All Plots",
                "title_alt2": "All Plots",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Residential Plot"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "12",
                "title": "Residential Plots",
                "title_alt2": "Plots",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Residential Plot"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "23",
                "title": "Plot Files",
                "title_alt2": "Plots",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Plot File"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "11",
                "title": "Commercial Plots",
                "title_alt2": "Commercial Plots",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Commercial Plot"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "19",
                "title": "Agricultural Land",
                "title_alt2": "Agricultural Land",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Agricultural Land"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "26",
                "title": "Plot Forms",
                "title_alt2": "Plot Forms",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Plot Form"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "27",
                "title": "Industrial Land",
                "title_alt2": "Industrial Land",
                "parent_id": "2",
                "title_alt1": "Industrial Land"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type_id": "3",
            "title": "Commercial",
            "title_alt2": "Commercial",
            "parent_id": "",
            "title_alt1": "Commercial Property",
            "child_list": "13,15,17,14,16,18",
            "childs": [
              {
                "type_id": "13",
                "title": "Offices",
                "title_alt2": "Offices",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Office"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "15",
                "title": "Shops",
                "title_alt2": "Shops",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Shop"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "17",
                "title": "Warehouses",
                "title_alt2": "Warehouses",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Warehouse"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "14",
                "title": "Factories",
                "title_alt2": "Factories",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Factory"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "16",
                "title": "Buildings",
                "title_alt2": "Buildings",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Building"
              },
              {
                "type_id": "18",
                "title": "Other",
                "title_alt2": "Other",
                "parent_id": "3",
                "title_alt1": "Other"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

My LogCat Error Detail is

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
    fragments.Types$ExpendableAdapter.getChildView()
```

Comment: `groupPosition` should not be greater than or equal to `propertyTypesList.size()` same applies to `childPosition` which should not be greater than or equal to `Utils.propertyTypesList.get(groupPosition).getChildList().size()`

Comment: But I can't find that line in the code you wrote above! Is that in the adapter?

Comment: as per your issue, variable should not have the value 7 as your list size is 7

Comment: Oh, so your app crashes when you navigate back from another activity? Like what, hitting the back button?

Comment: @Prashant but i placed all homes at index 0 and now my child array contain elements 0 to 7 and its placed at index 0 of propertyList also i placed all plots at index 0 of my child array that contains 0 to 6 elements placed at index 1 of propertyList and so with All Commercial at index 0 of childs array and that child array contains 0 to 6 elements and its placed at index 3 of propertyList

Comment: @RafaelCardoso yes as soon as i go back it crashes and this error cones seem like its not updating the array values and still getting previous values on the other side its showing wots inside the array as i have settled the all homes all plots and all commercial categories but when i click on them and try to go bak app crashes

Comment: Should i need to add a check somewhere??

Comment: I guess! Try to call `initItems()` when your fragment goes back. Take a look at  `addOnBackStackChangedListener` method to your fragment, or, if you are changing between activities, call `initItems()` on `onResume()`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso its Type name Fragment and i didnot use addOnBackStackChangedListener method here and i am jumping from one fragment to another

Comment: Thats what I am saying, add `addOnBackStackChangedListener` method to parse when the user goes back from one fragment to another. In this method, you init the ListView again, understand?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso thanks a lot i do it and then tell u the output

Comment: @RafaelCardoso It started working i called innit from onResume() Method placed inside my fragment Type the code i send u but as soon as i navigate bak the previous changes disappear and all homes all plots and all commercial hides

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75825/discussion-on-question-by-ans-jamil-indexoutofboundexception-at-getchildview-m).